# How to use TabIndent method for a word file using PHP COM

Tags: php, com

I am using PHP COM to export some contents from Database to Word Document.
I want to do some Left Indent in the Word Document using TabIndent method.

In VBA it is:
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabIndent(2)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839143.aspx

I want to use the same method in PHP COM but it is not working. My code is as below:

```
$word = new variant(com_get_active_object("word.application"));
$word->Selection->ParagraphFormat->TabIndent(2);
```

Comment: Any Suggestions/Answers Please..?